# How Reliable the Login System, Where Database Has No Unique Column and Email Can Be Duplicatable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am creating a login system where the database has no unique column and the email can be duplicatable.

Database Structure of users table

```
1. 'id' => unique, auto_increment, and primary_key
2. 'email' => not null,
3. 'password' => not null,
4. 'subdomain' => not null
```

Just for instance => example records in database may be

```
1.  id = 1
    email = me@me.com
    password = 12345
    subdomain = first

2.  id = 2
    email = me@me.com
    password = 12345
    subdomain = second
```

For instance, lets say,

1. I have a domain name called example.com with subdomains.
2. Login System takes email and password for authentication.
3. System manages the user login/register with subdomain
   (I mean user cannot access the route login/register without subdomain i.e https://example.com/login or
   https://example.com/register (will get 404 not found error).
   But with subdomain route https://**first**.example.com/login or https://**first**.example.com/register
   both are accessible and system works.
   During user registration the subdomain **first** will also be
   saved inside the user table column named 'subdomain'.
   During authentication, System will check for the email, password combination with subdomain for that
   particular user)
4. Now, if the same user tries to register for different subdomain (eg:
   https://**second**.example.com/login or https://**second**.example.com/register) and he uses the same
   email id (which user used for the first subdomain https://**first**.example.com/register) he can
   successfully register and can login to the system. (But each time login, the authentication system
   checks for the subdomain with email and password combination the session variables will be set based
   on the subdomain in the route)
5. if the user has not registered to anyother subdomain will not able to access those subdomain, unless
   he registers.
6. But both subdomain (or any subdomain in place) works using the same user table.

Note:
Login System is built using the php7.4, Laravel 7.* framework

My Question:
Will this approach causes any problem in future,
what can be expected from this type of login system,
Any suggestions are also welcome

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not just make `users` unique and link/relate domains to the account/user?

Comment: hi.. thanks for the reply: @brombeer , the requirement is that,  each subdomain points to a different website and each user needs to be registered to access the subdomain and its related unique content. All has to be on the same domain

Comment: Make a combined unique index on the `username`, `subdomain` columns…?!

Comment: @deceze thanks for the help... I didn't know about this. Thank you. Does this way of login system cause any problem in future??

Comment: Generally: no. But the devil is of course in the details…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is "How reliable". The answer is: It can be very reliable.

You still have a unicity in Domain+email. You will need to rework your auth middlewares and have the Domain as a requirement for each interraction with authentified routes (session, url, or other solutions) And rework your Authentification controllers.

About the structure, it's up to you to decide if you should have:

- a unique user across all domains:

  - Have a pivot table between users and domains to link the user to each domain with the password in the pivot table (if you want different password per domain)
  - Pros: You can have only one profile editing across all domains.
  - Cons: manage a many to many relation.
- Multiple users with same email but unique combination email + domain.

  - Pros: none
  - Cons:

    - profile updating (password/image/statuses/...)
    - redondancy and lack of integrity
    - Relation between users and other models that are independant of the domain.